# Develop Adobe .jsx extentions in webstorm

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript

Is there a way to include the adobe ExtendScript library into a webstorm project? Basically I'm trying to use .jsx files syntax inside my project. 
I tried to lookup for the extend script core lib files on my drive, without success

Answer (score 0):

These guys have set up a pretty good way to generate the necessary .jsx: https://github.com/yearbookmachine/extendscript-api-documentation

You can get precompiled libraries here: https://github.com/yearbookmachine/extendscript-api-documentation#documentation-and-autocomplete-in-ides